# Swift Circle Image View

Tags: ios, swift, imageview

I'm trying to create a circle imageView for a user's profile picture in my tableViewCell. I've set up the constraints in my code like so,

```
        cell.creatorImageView = UIImageView()
        cell.creatorImageView?
            .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.creatorImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "memoryCardBack")
        cell.creatorImageView!.layer.cornerRadius =
            (cell.creatorImageView?.bounds.width)! / 2
        cell.creatorImageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.profileCreatorView?.addSubview(cell.creatorImageView!)

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.creatorImageView!, attribute: .Width,
            relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1, constant: 44).active = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.creatorImageView!,
            attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil,
            attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44)
            .active = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.creatorImageView!, attribute: .Top
            , relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.profileCreatorView,
            attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 5).active = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.creatorImageView!,
            attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: cell.profileCreatorView, attribute: .CenterX,
            multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
```

I'm not too sure why the imageView isn't becoming a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CALayer` and `cornerRadius` to do it:

```
YourView.layer.cornerRadius = halfOfYourViewWidthOrHeight
YourView.clipsToBounds = true
YourView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: I found the problem right after I posted this actually, where I was setting the corner radius it wasn't dividing the width in half. I think this is because I'm setting the corner radius before I'm setting the width constraint.